# how to make Search query in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How to make a search query in SQLite ?

Suppose I have a table,

[image]

I want search in 3 fields,

If I search for string `anil Hno Delhi` then,

[image]

I tried to concatenate all 3 fields and then given a search query for that concatenated column using `like` but its not fulfilling my requirement.

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: What query you used? Share here

Comment: SELECT * FROM yourTableName WHERE FirstName = 'anil' AND Address Like 'Hno%Delhi'

Comment: I bet he/she won´t like the answer until full code is posted...

Comment: I bet the OP already tried a (WRONG) query. It's only to replace his/her query with my (working) one.

Answer (score 0):

its simple

```
String sql ="SELECT firstName,LastName FROm table where criteria=?"; 

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
```